# Reading Pre-OCR'd PDF in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, ocr

I am trying to use iTextSharp to read a PDF that has already been OCRd by another program. The text in the PDF is basically a table. I can successfully get the text with the following method:

```
public static string ExtractTextFromPdf(string path)
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
    {
        StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            t.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()));
        }

        return t.ToString();
    }
}
```

However, the text that is returned from this method is inserting newline characters in places that seem strange. For example, here is the following excerpt from the PDF:

[image]

When I open this pdf in foxit reader and view it as text, "FULE DATE" and "SUBCATEGORY" are on the same "horizontal line". However, when using iTextSharp it puts a newline character `\n` after "FULE DATE" like so:

`FULE DATE\nSUBCATEGORY`

Why is this?

Comment: You don't share the pdf itself, so I can only speculate. It sounds like the invisible text (which the ocr program added where the image shows text) is not exactly at the same height.

Comment: In addition to what @mkl commented, please understand that there is no concept of lines, paragraphs or even words in PDF. Your OCR engine "invented" those concepts to the best of its abilities. So even small deviations in positioning can cause misinterpretations.